# How to get access token from spring authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to setup spring authorization server by using the [getting started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html) guide.

server starts up fine but I am not able to fetch access token using rest API and getting following error:

> org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: client_id

I am using following Rest API:

http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token

and passing following payload in request:

```
grant_type:client_credential
client_id:oidc-client
client_secret:secret
```

and using basic authentication with following username and password:

```
username: user
password: password
```

I am not sure what the above error is pointing me to. Am I using wrong end point or am I using wrong client_id and client_secret.

Would appreciate any help.